# Trouble centering Divs?

Tags: html, css

I apologize if this is a basic question, but i'm having trouble centering four divs. All four green divs have a float left, then there is a wrapper div (blue). I want to center the four divs but have them aligned like this (On a larger resolution they are not displayed along the middle). So that when reducing the screen size the `div`s will float underneath each other.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/qvu712tj/**](http://jsfiddle.net/qvu712tj/)

```css
#blog-wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align: center;
}
.blog-section {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blog-wrapper">
  <div class="blog-section"></div>
  <div class="blog-section"></div>
  <div class="blog-section"></div>
  <div class="blog-section"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this makes sense please could anyone help?

Comment: This is because of the float. You need either to set their width in % or to remove float with a media query when the screen is too small.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the problem is the divs on centering

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/Qj8G89T)

Comment: You can also use display: inline-block and text-align: center : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/RWvVOo?editors=110

Comment: @RyanHolmes you delete [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373569/css-selector-to-effect-the-another-div) but here you have an approach https://jsfiddle.net/adkue36x/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.blog-section {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px 2.5%;
  float: left;
/* padding: 5px; */ 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much really appreciate, this is just what i'm after!

Answer (score 0):

use percentage instead of px for margin and padding

```
.blog-section{
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1.5%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.blog-section{
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 12px 1%;
  float: left;
}
```